# How to create random circle on flutter canvas?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How to create something similar in the flutter. I not getting an idea of how to begin something. Should I use Custom Painter or stack view in the flutter

[image]

Comment: if you have dozens of circles use `CustomPaint`, otherwise `Stack` is good enough

Comment: do you have any idea on how to arrange in a random fashion without overlapping @pskink??

Comment: @PratikKatariya I wanna do the same design but I am not able to find any solution, if you have any solution so please let me know.